# How can I show div element only on specific query string?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to show this particular div element only when the user has a query string like `?mode=showdiv` at the end of the query string. Otherwise, do not show this div.

What's the best way to do this?

Here's my div:

```
<div>
     <p class ="Call-Customer-Support">Call customer support at 555-555-5555.   </p>
     <div class="Rectangle">
     <img class="call icon-image" src="images/call.png" />
     <a class="Call-Support" href="tel:555-555-5555">Call Support</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

I'm using ASP.NET web forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check it using the `Request.QueryString` in an if block:

```
<% if (Request.QueryString["mode"]!=null && Request.QueryString["mode"] == "showdiv") {%>

<div>
     <p class ="Call-Customer-Support">Call customer support at 555-555-5555.   </p>
     <div class="Rectangle">
     <img class="call icon-image" src="images/call.png" />
     <a class="Call-Support" href="tel:555-555-5555">Call Support</a>
     </div>
</div>

<%}%>
```

Comment: Best solution, thank you! I will accept in a few minutes! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all , you need to set an `ID` to the div you need to **Hide/Show** as below :

```
<div id="div1">
     <p class ="Call-Customer-Support">Call customer support at 555-555-5555.   </p>
     <div class="Rectangle">
     <img class="call icon-image" src="images/call.png" />
     <a class="Call-Support" href="tel:555-555-5555">Call Support</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Then ,get the value of your `Query String` as below:

```
string mode = Request.QueryString["mode"];
     if(mode =="showdiv")
     {
        div1.visible=true;
     }
```

Comment: it is not a server side control

Comment: He/She can add a `runat="server"` property to the **div** tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="mainDiv">
     <p class ="Call-Customer-Support">Call customer support at 555-555-5555.   </p>
     <div class="Rectangle">
     <img class="call icon-image" src="images/call.png" />
     <a class="Call-Support" href="tel:555-555-5555">Call Support</a>
     </div>
</div>



if (<% Request.QueryString["mode"] %> == "showdiv") {
var item =  getElementById('mainDiv');
item.style.display = 'none';
}else{
item.style.display = 'block';
}
```